# How to pause and resume UIView.animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have an image, I animate it with this code, in viewDidAppear:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(10.5, delay:0.0, options: [], animations:{
self.myImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 200)
}, completion: nil)
```

I want to pause the animation when I tap `myPauseButton`, and resume the animation if I tap it again.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

2 functions to pause and resume animation, I take from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1673/_index.html) and convert to Swift.

```
func pauseLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    layer.speed = 0.0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
}

func resumeLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.timeOffset
    layer.speed = 1.0
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0
    layer.beginTime = 0.0
    let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}
```

I have a button to pause or resume the animation which is initiated in `viewDidLoad`:

```
var pause = false
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.5) {
        self.image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 200)
    }
}

@IBAction func changeState() {
    let layer = image.layer
    pause = !pause
    if pause {
        pauseLayer(layer)
    } else {
        resumeLayer(layer)
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple, elegant, just perfect Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a great deal! However, when the layer is paused and the view is rotated, the app hangs. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I signed in just to thank you and vote up! UIViewProbertyAnimator is soo stupid, Thank you man

Comment: In a scenario where we need to add an extra seconds to the resumed animation, how would we do that?

Answer (score 12):

Here is Swift 3 version of that answer + I moved those function to an extension

```
extension CALayer {
    func pause() {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = self.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
        self.speed = 0.0
        self.timeOffset = pausedTime
    }

    func resume() {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = self.timeOffset
        self.speed = 1.0
        self.timeOffset = 0.0
        self.beginTime = 0.0
        let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = self.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
        self.beginTime = timeSincePause
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Since iOS 10 provides `UIViewPropertyAnimator` you can solve your problem easier.

Declare these properties in your controller:

```
var animationPaused = false
lazy var animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 10.5, curve: .easeInOut, animations: {

    self.myImage.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: 200)
})
```

Add the following code to the tap handler of `myPauseButton`:

```
if self.animator.state == .active { // Don't start or pause the animation when it's finished

    self.animationPaused = !self.animationPaused
    self.animationPaused ? self.animator.pauseAnimation() : self.animator.startAnimation()
}
```

Start the animation in `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)` with these lines of code:

```
self.animationPaused = false
self.animator.startAnimation()
```