# iOS animation stopped after the background/foreground transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I'm writing a page that checks if a device has been linked to the system.
The page sends requests every 2 seconds for 6 times, during that time (may be up to 10 seconds) the page shows an animating loading circle.

Here is the problem: when I press the home button and immediately reopen the app, **the animation stops**.

Here is what I know:

### Two ways of implementing the animation:

1. `CABasicAnimation`:

   ```
   CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
   rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
   rotationAnimation.toValue = @(2 * M_PI);
   rotationAnimation.duration = 1.5;
   rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
   [loadingCircle.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
   ```
2. `UIView animateWithDuration...`:

   ```
   - (void)rotateView:(UIView *)view {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
           view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform, M_PI);
       } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
           if (finished) {
               [self rotateView:view];
           }
       }];
   }
   ...
   - viewDidLoad {
       ...
       [self rotateView:loadingCircle];
   }
   ```

I know that in the first implementation, setting `rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;` will resume the animation.

My question is: when I'm using the second implementation what is the equivalent way to achieve the same effect.

Comment: call the animation method in applicationDidBecomeActive in appdelegate class

Comment: I do it by subscribing notification in my local class. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using UIView animateWithDuration actually applies the same effects the view's underlying `layer` property, so you can pause and resume like this.

```
func pauseLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
    layer.speed = 0.0
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
}

func resumeLayer(layer: CALayer) {
    let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.timeOffset
    layer.speed = 1.0
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0
    layer.beginTime = 0.0
    let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil) - pausedTime
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
}
```

You'll have to translate that into objective-c yourself, sorry. Credit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994520/how-to-pause-and-resume-uiview-animatewithduration) for the original solution.

You can subscribe to the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification via `NSNotificationCenter` if you'd like to keep the code local instead of putting in the app delegate. There is a matching `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification you can use to restart the animation when coming back.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried the notification method and it works well. :]