# Is there any way to cache UIViewController or UIView Animation state

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have viewcontroller A and viewcontroller B.
vcA has a continuously animation with repeat and autoreverse.
When user push to vcB and then back to vcA, animation reset to beginning state. In this case, how to continue the animation at the time user push to vcB when vcA come back again.

- VCA : animation 70% => Push to VCB.
- VCB : back to vca => VCA : animation 71%..72%...

Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us what kind of animation are you using, is it progress indicator or an UIViewanimation? Please be descriptive, put some code or explain in detail way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pause and resume UIView.animateWithDuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33994520/how-to-pause-and-resume-uiview-animatewithduration)

Comment: Vinaykrishnan, CABasicAnimation(opacity, scale) and UIviewanimation(scale, alpha) in a UIView. 
The animation look like fadein-fadeout but much more complicated.

Comment: Prashant Tukadiya that link does not work in my case.

Comment: Have a look at this could help you or give you some hint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306870/is-there-a-way-to-pause-a-cabasicanimation